# issue with wordpress theme twenty-twenty-two and large table on mobile

Tags: wordpress-theming, responsive

on my website wordpress + theme twenty-twenty-two, I've a large table on a page that shows the schedule and prices.

It's unreadable on mobile phone because the size of the screen it show only the first 2-3 column. on computer it's ok.

The theme twenty-twenty-two is responsive.
What can you advise to make this table more comfortable on smartphones?

Here is the url (access it with mobile phone to reproduce the issue): https://axelingo.com/horaires-cours-anglais/

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found some wp plugins to do that easily. wp table builder fr example as an option for responsive. This build the raw vertically basically when on mobile phone.